# How to enable context menu for certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I have disabled context menu(mouse right click) for Document. 
    $(document).bind('contextmenu',function(){return false;});
Now I want to enable context menu for certain input.
    $('#nickname').bind('contextmenu', function (){return true;});
But it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return true/false from document context menu handler depending on the element you clicked on. See `.target` property of `event`.

```
$(document).bind('contextmenu',function(event){
  if (event.target == document.querySelector("#nickname")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

See full example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqmXZJ?editors=1010

Try to `console.log(event)` when not sure what to do with events, there are a lot of helpful properties there.